# SQL Server 2008: What does it mean to grant a user "AUTHORIZATION" over a schema?

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, authorization

I see the following in one of my database scripts:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [ContosoSchema] AUTHORIZATION [ContosoDeveloper]
GO
```

My question:

> In SQL Server 2008, what does it mean to grant a user "AUTHORIZATION" over a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `AUTHORIZATION` [confers ownership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx) of a database-contained entity.

Comment: That si correct, but is not restricted to database-contained entities alone, since the database itself can be changed ownership (`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE:<dbname>` which is the same as `sp_changedbowner`). Also endpoints can be changed authorization (ownership), but are instance level entities.